# My Minecraft world has just disappeared and it isn't in the saves folder either

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I've been playing on a Minecraft world (1.15.2 Java edition) for quite a while and one day I tried to open that world but just after the chunks loaded, my laptop crashed. I went back on to Minecraft and my world wasn't in the world list. I looked this up on Google and everyone said to check my saves folder. I did this but my world wasn't there. I haven't ever made a backup of the world because I didn't think a problem like this was likely. I've spent hours on this world. Can someone please help?

Comment: @pppery According to the OP, the world is no longer in the saves folder.

Answer (score 0):

That happens when the chunks don't load fully and it corrupts your save due to lag and the fact that there may be large parts of the world missing, so Minecraft deletes it or your computer deletes it.